# Android NDK: no error or warning when calling undeclared function

Tags: android-ndk, undefined-function

I'm building a library in C with the Android NDK which links to some static libraries provided by another team.  If I call a function that's defined in one of those libraries, but not declared by any of my imported headers, I get no error or warning from the compiler.  It looks like the compiler assumes that the arguments I pass in are of the correct types.  I don't like this, because I might call the function incorrectly and not know it.

For example, if the static library contains a function like "void MyFunc(int a, char *b);", then I expect each of the following to produce an error:

- MyFunc();
- MyFunc(1, 2);
- MyFunc(1, '2', 3);

If I include a declaration of the function, then the compiler enforces that the number and types of the parameters are correct.

Is there a way to tell the NDK compiler to show an error or warning when a call is made to an undeclared function?

Comment: OK, I got it.  In Android.mk, add "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" or "-Werror-implicit-function-declaration" to the LOCAL_CFLAGS variable.

Comment: It's usually good to just throw in `-Wall`, which includes `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` for C (and about 28 others).  It's not actually "all" warnings, just the generally useful ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android.mk, add `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` or `-Werror-implicit-function-declaration` to the `LOCAL_CFLAGS` variable.  Or add `-Wall`; that's good too.  (Thanks, fadden!)